# piping with requestjs in node 0.10 vs higher version

Tags: node.js, requestjs

so I need some help understanding what exactly happens when piping requests and if there is a difference between node 0.10.x and 4.5.x

I have something like this:

```
function(req, res, next){
  if(req.method === 'PUT'){
    var putOptions = {
      uri: config.url + req.url,
      headers: {
        token: req.session.token
      },
      jason: req.body
    };
    var r = request.put(putOptions, callback);
    return req.pipe(r).pipe(res);
  }
}
```

now this works fine in node 0.10.x, however in 4.5.x I get "write after end" error, unless I remove `req.pipe`-part and just do `r.pipe(res)`, then it works fine in 4.5.x.

Now I would like some help in understanding what the difference is between these two, what really happens, and why it behaves differently in different node versions.

Thanks for any help!

**---Update---**

Ok so when I tried `req.pipe(r, {end: false}).pipe(res)` it worked in 4.5.x, I'm no longer getting "write after end"-error ... I'm still a bit confused about why there is a difference.. The docs regarding pipes doesn't seem to have changed since 0.10